# Is it possible add create rest apis without restarting server?

Tags: spring-rest

I am trying to implement a server which has to offer REST APIs. As the time goes by I may have to add new REST APIs based on the need of that hour. Well I can do it with a simple spring REST API service where I can add the new API and re-deploy the application to server.

But it would have been nicer if I could just go on adding APIs to the server whenever there is a need without even stopping the server ! Is it even possible ?

I would appreciate any input on this topic.

Comment: Maybe you could consider Amazon's [Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html)

Comment: Thanks, but anything other than aws Lamda ?

Comment: I read somewhere REST APIs can be written in a python script and then added at any point to the server. I also read it can be added to the tomcat server along with spring application, if any. But is that a good idea ?

Comment: if you are willing to allow any framework and any language, then this question is too broad.

Comment: I would prefer it to be Java and spring but so far I haven't found a way through . If at all its possible with a popular framework or language I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Spring, but surely REST APIs can be written in Python and once running can be served through Tomcat as with any other HTTP server.

The question is, why don't you want to re-start the server? Is it because you are afraid of downtime and missing out on some requests?

If so probably you could adopt one of these two strategies (laid out in layman's terms):

1. `Load Balancing`: You have 2+ servers running in a cluster behind a common HTTP server (let's say A, B, C and D, for example): bring offline A and B, update them, bring them back online while bringing offline C and D, update them, and bring them all back online.
2. `Blue/Green`: Similar to the previous one but with 2 clusters (one active and one idle - could be just 1 server per cluster, doesn't matter): update the idle one, swap it with the currently active one (i.e. channel all traffic from one to the other using the HTTP server).

Comment: Yes its the downtime and also the process of compiling the whole code, testing and pushing the app to server . Its absolutely doable , I guess that's how servers are maintained. I just wanted to know if we can go adding new APIs during run time without much hassle . Especially if there are frequent requests for new APIs.